# Project Euler prob. 4 in Python

Tags: python

I stumbled upon Project Euler.
This is my code for [Problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4):

```
def find():
    for a in range(999,99,-1):
        for b in range(999,99,-1):
            v = a * b
            if str(v) == str(v)[::-1]:
                print (v)
```

My console isn't displaying any result though :/. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is "Project Euler prob. 4" and do you call this `find()` function anywhere in your code?

Comment: you need to add some more detail to your code. What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is problem 4 in project euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4), and with some slight modifications of your code, it runs:

```
def find():
    n = 0
    for a in xrange(999, 100, -1):
        for b in xrange(a, 100, -1):
            x = a * b
            if x > n:
                s = str(a * b)
                if s == s[::-1]:
                     n = a * b
    print n

find()
```

Comment: I'm new to coding, so I was just curious if there was any difference in how the code would run when putting in "a" versus "999" for the range of b. Also, for the print function, why is it important to put it outside of the for loop? Thanks so much!

Comment: putting just `999` in the range of b tests it only against one number, repeatedly.  putting `a` in the `for` loop changes the number that is tried each time, which ends up giving you the correct answer. :-) happy coding!

Comment: no problem!  Keep on and you'll be a Pythonista in no time :-)

Answer (score 0):

To display your result you need to call the function/method in python after defining it

```
def find():
    for a in range(999,99,-1):
        for b in range(999,99,-1):
            v = a * b
            if str(v) == str(v)[::-1]:
                print (v)

find() //Calls the function find()
```